# Update query for API in codeigniter is not working

Tags: php, android, mysql, api, codeigniter

i want to write a API for updating data in sql. I am using CI for it.I am new to this field.while i have written it is not working in localhost itself .Can anyone help me? I am attaching my controller and model here.it is showing an error like this page is not working

```
    function editprofile($id,$data) {
                $this->db->where(array('user_id' => $id));
            $this->db->update('registrationdetails', $data);
                    if(!empty($id))
                    {
                        $result = true;
                    } else {
                        $result = false;
                    }
                    return $result;
                }
public function updateuser()
                {
                    $adminId = 1;
                    $AUTHENTIC_KEY = "4u0IOxa1YTwNo38QjArD9ysW6PgVnbX7vtlJ";
                    $user_id=2;
                    $firstname ="aiswarya";
                    $lastname ="mathew";
                    $email ="aiswarya@gmail.com";
                    $password ="aiswarya";
                    $confirmpassword ="aiswarya";
                    $contactnumber ="999999999";
                    $gender ="female";
                    $address ="canada"; 
                    $department ="cse";
                    $designation ="swe";
          $Admindetails = $this->common->CheckValidAdmin($adminId,$AUTHENTIC_KEY);
                    if($Admindetails != false)
                    {
                        $validAdmin = array('authentication_key' => $Admindetails->authentication_key,
                                                    'admin_id' => $Admindetails->id
                                                    );
        $data = array();
                        $data = array('firstname'=>$firstname,'lastname'=>$lastname,'email'=>$email,'password'=>$password,'confirmpassword'=>$confirmpassword,'contactnumber'=>$contactnumber,'gender'=>$gender,'address'=>$address,'department'=>$department,'designation'=>$designation);                                         
  $status = $this->user->editprofile($user_id,$data);
                                        if($status == true)
                                        {
                                            $response = array('status' => 200,
                                                              'message' => 'updated successfully',
                                                'admin_details' => $validAdmin
                                                              );

                                        } else {
                                            $response = array('status' => 404,
                                                              'message' => 'unable to add, please try again',
                                                              'admin_details' => $validAdmin);
                                        }

        } else { 
                            $response = array('status' => 404,
                                              'message' => 'Authentication Failed');
                    }
                    echo json_encode($response);

                }
```

Comment: If it shows  an error, add the error message

Comment: This page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: where is your variable $data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    function editprofile($data) {

         if(!empty($data['user_id']))
         {
            $this->db->where(array('user_id' => $data['user_id']));
            $this->db->update('registrationdetails', $data);
            $result = true;
         } else {
            $result = false;
         }
            return $result;
  }
  public function updateuser()
  {
      $data['adminId'] = 1;
      $data['AUTHENTIC_KEY'] = "4u0IOxa1YTwNo38QjArD9ysW6PgVnbX7vtlJ";
      $data['user_id']=2;
      $data['firstname'] ="aiswarya";
      $data['lastname'] ="mathew";
      $data['email'] ="aiswarya@gmail.com";
      $data['password'] ="aiswarya";
      $data['confirmpassword'] ="aiswarya";
      $data['contactnumber'] ="999999999";
      $data['gender'] ="female";
      $data['address'] ="canada";   
      $data['department'] ="cse";
      $data['designation'] ="swe";

      $Admindetails = $this->common->CheckValidAdmin($data['adminId'],$data['AUTHENTIC_KEY']);
      if($Admindetails != false)
      {
          $validAdmin = array('authentication_key' => $Admindetails->authentication_key,
                'admin_id' => $Admindetails->id);

            $status = $this->user->editprofile($data);
            if($status == true)
            {
                    $response = array('status' => 200,
                                    'message' => 'updated successfully',
                                    'admin_details' => $validAdmin
                                );

            } else {
                $response = array('status' => 404,
                                'message' => 'unable to add, please try again',
                                'admin_details' => $validAdmin);
            }

        } else { 
                $response = array('status' => 404,
                                'message' => 'Authentication Failed');
   }
   echo json_encode($response);
```

}

Comment: {"status":404,"message":"unable to add, please try again","admin_details":{"authentication_key":"4u0IOxa1YTwNo38QjArD9ysW6PgVnbX7vtlJ","admin_id":"1"}}

Comment: 404 means page not found check your route.

Comment: it is not entering  to if else statment

Comment: change in your model $data['id'] to $data['user_id'] check edited answer.

Comment: This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500